# converting XYZ color to RGB

Tags: formula, rgb, color-space

color-primary transformations

Does anyone know of any formula for converting a XYZ  to an RGB value?

how   find rgb from XYZ in this pic?
[image]

Comment: I'm sure wikipedia does. What research have you done?

Comment: There's no generic "XYZ to RGB" because "RGB" doesn't have a precise meaning. You need to choose a specific color space that has specific primaries, such as [sRGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB).

Comment: There is a lot of math involved. My recommendation would be [Bruce Lindbloom's Website](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_RGB_XYZ_Matrix.html). It contains all the formulas, parameters and background knowledge you need to konverta a color from one color space to another.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a simple [linear relationship between RGB and XYZ spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB#The_sRGB_transfer_function_.28.22gamma.22.29) (if you wish you can express this in matrix form in the obvious way):

`R =  3.2404542*X - 1.5371385*Y - 0.4985314*Z
G = -0.9692660*X + 1.8760108*Y + 0.0415560*Z
B =  0.0556434*X - 0.2040259*Y + 1.0572252*Z`

However, if what you meant is sRGB space, then additional [non-linear transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB#Specification_of_the_transformation) needs to be applied to each component: `R=adj(R)`, `G=adj(G)`, and `B=adj(B)`. The `adj` function is defined as follows:

```
function adj(C) {
  if (Abs(C) < 0.0031308) {
    return 12.92 * C;
  }
  return 1.055 * Math.pow(C, 0.41666) - 0.055;
}
```

Comment: That matrix is of sRGB, and sRGB is not the only RGB color space.